# jQuery Address Remove Last Url From History

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, browser-history, jquery-address

We are utilizing the jQuery Address plugin in our ASP.NET MVC ajax application to handle deep linking and the preservation of history.  Whenever you want to navigate to a new page, you simply make the following call:

```
$.address.value([some url])
```

Our app has a very detailed user management system that allows our users to define which users have access to which functions in the app.  We decorate each action method with a customized Authorize attribute that determines whether or not the user has permission to use the function supplied by that action method.  The authorization works great but the problem is that if the user doesn't have permission to utilize the given action method, the browser url still reflects as if they are on the page of the link they clicked.

For instance, if the url /SomeController/UnpermittedAction represents an action method that the user should not be able to utilize, when they click on the link to that method, we execute the following

```
$.address.value('/SomeController/UnpermittedAction')
```

Then, the action returns an Unauthorized response and we display to the user that they are not permitted to utilize that function.  But, understandably, the user's browser window now shows:

```
somedomain.com/#/SomeController/UnpermittedAction
```

That in of itself isn't really a problem, the problem is that if the user goes to some other page and then clicks the back browser button, they see the unauthorized message again and it appears somewhat confusing as they aren't sure why they are seeing that message.  Ideally, if they click the back button, we would want to return the user back to the last page they were authorized to use.

My question is, is there any way to remove the unpermitted action url from the browser history and/or the jQuery address history?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript try

```
        $.address.history(false);
        $.address.value(newurl);
        $.address.history(true);
```

This will replace the last history entry with the new url